# Setting Container Controller (Root View Controller) as Delegate for View Controllers in UITabBarController

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, swift5

I'm trying to set a Container Controller (Root View Controller) as the delegate for a Nav Bar Item for a View Controller in a Tab Bar Controller and cannot figure out how to do this without using:

```
let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
```

This code works as I'd like it to:

```
 let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

    guard let doghouseViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DoghouseVC") as? DoghouseViewController else { return }
    doghouseViewController.delegate = rootViewController as? DoghouseViewControllerDelegate
    let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: doghouseViewController)
    guard let statsViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StatsVC") as? StatsViewController else { return }
    statsViewController.delegate = rootViewController as? StatsViewControllerDelegate
    let nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: statsViewController)

    dailyWrapUpViewController = DailyWrapUpViewController()

    guard let calendarViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CalendarVC") as? CalendarViewController else { return }
    calendarViewController.delegate = rootViewController as? CalendarViewControllerDelegate
    let nav3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: calendarViewController)
    guard let settingsViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsVC") as? SettingsViewController else { return }
    settingsViewController.delegate = rootViewController as? SettingsViewControllerDelegate
    let nav4 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: settingsViewController)

    doghouseViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Doghouse", image: UIImage(named: "doghouse"), tag: 0)
    statsViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Stats", image: UIImage(named: "stats"), tag: 1)

    // Custom Doggy Bag Button
    let controller2 = UIViewController()

    calendarViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Calendar", image: UIImage(named: "calendar"), tag: 3)
    settingsViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "More", image: UIImage(named: "more"), tag: 4)

    viewControllers = [nav1, nav2, controller2, nav3, nav4]

    // Use the view controller reference to select the second tab
    selectedViewController = nav1
```

But, 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0 and if I try to change it using the following as an example, the delegate functionality doesn't work (button gets pushed, but Container Controller instance does not receive):

```
let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController as! ContainerController
```

For more context, the Container Controller (Root View Controller) is a side menu that slides out on the tap of a NavBar Item within the TabBarController.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
let sceneDelegate = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first!.delegate as! SceneDelegate

    guard let doghouseViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DoghouseVC") as? DoghouseViewController else { return }
    doghouseViewController.delegate = sceneDelegate.window!.rootViewController as? DoghouseViewControllerDelegate
    let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: doghouseViewController)
    guard let statsViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StatsVC") as? StatsViewController else { return }
    statsViewController.delegate = sceneDelegate.window!.rootViewController as? StatsViewControllerDelegate
    let nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: statsViewController)

    dailyWrapUpViewController = DailyWrapUpViewController()

    guard let calendarViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CalendarVC") as? CalendarViewController else { return }
    calendarViewController.delegate = sceneDelegate.window!.rootViewController as? CalendarViewControllerDelegate
    let nav3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: calendarViewController)
    guard let settingsViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsVC") as? SettingsViewController else { return }
    settingsViewController.delegate = sceneDelegate.window!.rootViewController as? SettingsViewControllerDelegate
    let nav4 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: settingsViewController)

    doghouseViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Doghouse", image: UIImage(named: "doghouse"), tag: 0)
    statsViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Stats", image: UIImage(named: "stats"), tag: 1)

    // Custom Doggy Bag Button
    let controller2 = UIViewController()

    calendarViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Calendar", image: UIImage(named: "calendar"), tag: 3)
    settingsViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "More", image: UIImage(named: "more"), tag: 4)

    viewControllers = [nav1, nav2, controller2, nav3, nav4]

    // Use the view controller reference to select the second tab
    selectedViewController = nav1
```